# Google PageSpeed Insights - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn') at e

Tags: pagespeed

when I run a test or my party's website -- https://www.wspus.org -- on Google PageSpeed Insights, it says under 'Best Practices' that a browser error was logged to the console and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it. It says the source is jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js?ver=4ffc46285234:14:41. Anybody got any ideas on how to resolve this?

I've tried reaching out to FlyingPress, since this only started happening after I turned on 'Delay JavaScript," but they weren't sure how to fix it, since I was already excluding jquery.